# Why is resistivity of conductor inversely proportional to the area of the conductor?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

A simple Physics question regarding Ohm's law. The resistivity of the conductor is inversely proportional to the area of the conductor. I would like to have a simple explanation for this.

> How does resistivity increase if the area decreases in a conductor?

Comment: "The resistivity of the conductor is inversely proportional to the area of the conductor." Your answer is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

You mean: The *resistance* of a conductor is inversely proportional to the area. [Resistivity is a property of the material of which the conductor is made, and is independent of the size or shape of the conductor.]

You can imagine making up a cylindrical conductor from two strands of semicircular cross-section (running lengthways). If each strand has a resistance $R_{semi},$ then the complete conductor will have a resistance $R$ of $\frac{1}{2}R_{semi}$ because the strands are in parallel. [It doesn't matter that the strands are in contact all along and not just at the ends, because no current will flow between them.]

So a wire of twice the cross-sectional area (but the same length and material) has half the resistance.

You can easily extend the argument to show that resistance is inversely proportional to cross-sectional area (for a given length and material).

Comment: While resistivity is an intrinsec property of the material, if the dimensions are small enough then ballistic conduction might take over and the resistivity will certainly be different than for a larger sample of the exact same material.

Comment: I judged that the question-asker was concerned with resistances of everyday pieces of wire and not with very small specimens of conductor.

Comment: I understand. I was just pointing out that your sentence " [Resistivity is a property of the material of which the conductor is made, and is independent of the size or shape of the conductor.]" is not strictly true. My remark is very informative for the curious physics student who wants to dig deeper into this matter.

Comment: Also for the curious student: DC is assumed. But in AC applications the skin effect may become important. In the limiting case, resistance is then proportional to circumference (radius).

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson, it wouldn't make sense to even talk about resistivity for a sample small enough that those effects matter.

Comment: @ThePhoton then it's another point showing that the sentence "[Resistivity is a property of the material of which the conductor is made, and is independent of the size or shape of the conductor.]" does not always hold.

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson, it's very common we talk about materials having intrinisic properties that aren't well defined for microscopic samples.  Thermal conductivity, Young's modulus, etc., would be either different or ill-defined for such small samples, but we don't usually footnote any mention of these properties to remind people of that fact.

Comment: As long as the footnote doesn't become the headline...

Answer (score 1):

Think of the analogy of water flowing in a pipe. Water flows through a pipe more easily the greater the cross sectional area. Similarly, current will flow through a conductor more easily the greater the cross sectional area of the conductor.

However, it is the “resistance” of the conductor not its “resistivity” that varies inversely with the cross sectional area of the conductor. The “resistivity” of a conductor is a material property of the conductor.

The resistance of a conductor is given by

$$R=\frac {ρL}{A}$$

Where

$R$ = conductor resistance in Ohms

$ρ$ = the resistivity of the conductor material in Ohm-meter

$L$ = the length of the conductor in meters

$A$ = the cross sectional area of the conductor in square meters.

Hope this helps

Comment: Poor analogy. The flow of a liquid in a pipe is not constant over its cross section (in the case of laminar flow it is parabolic profile from zero at the walls which results in the Poiseuille $R^4$ law). But in an electrical wire, current density is constant over its cross section (in DC applications).

Comment: @Pieter I never said the flow of a liquid in a pipe is constant over its cross section. Don't put words in my mouth. I'm going to restate this one more time.

Comment: @Pieter Fluid motion is really complex. Your example is one model. As any other, it's not always valid. Anyways, the fact that the velocity profile varies along the cross-section doesn't mean that the net effect is what the answerer says.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are concerned with homogeneous and isotropic ohmic conductors in the diffusive regime. As others have pointed out already, the *(specific) resistivity* is a material property independent of the dimensions of the specimen.

We are now going to think about how *resistance* depends on the cross sectional area of the conductor perpendicular to the direction of current flow. Suppose we apply a constant dc voltage to the conductor of cross sectional area $A$ and resistance $R_A$. Then the current flowing through it is given according to Ohm's law by
$$ I_A = \frac{U}{R_A}.$$
**This current is homogeneously distributed across the cross sectional area of the conductor.**
This property will now help us to draw the right conclusions.

If we reduce the cross sectional area of the same conductor to $a$ (say, we cut the rest of the conductor away), but keep the voltage $U$ the same, the current will be reduced in proportion to the area reduction, i.e.,
$$ I_a = \frac{a}{A}I_A = \frac{a}{A}\frac{U}{R_A}.$$
At the same time, the current $I_a$ is, according to Ohm's law,
$$ I_a = \frac{U}{R_a},$$
where $R_a$ is the resistance of the resistor with reduced cross-sectional area.
Comparing the two equations for $I_a$ we see that
$$ R_a = \frac{R_AA}{a}.$$
Since in our problem, the product $R_AA$ is simply a constant given by the conductor with the initial cross section $A$, you see that the resistance $R_a$ of the conductor with reduced cross sectional area $a$ is inversely proportional to $a$.